# Catch block wrapping a function that throws inside a setTimeout not executed

Tags: javascript, function, try-catch

Experienced something strange recently, none of the catch blocks get executed:

```js
function funcWillThrow() {
  try {
    setTimeout(() => {
      throw "Has thrown";
    }, 3000);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}

function caller() {
  funcWillThrow();
}

caller();
```

and

```js
function funcWillThrow() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      throw "Has thrown";
    }, 3000);
}

function caller() {
  funcWillThrow();
}

try {
  caller();
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

And according to the [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw)

> Execution of the current function will stop (the statements after
> throw won't be executed), and control will be passed to the first
> catch block in the call stack. If no catch block exists among caller
> functions, the program will terminate.

My guess is that something is happening with the callstack as stated in the docs. Any ideas as to what might be happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout` calls the supplied function at a later time (3 seconds later in your specific code), and by then the function which called `setTimeout` has long since terminated.

To catch the exception in your later function, put the error handling in that function:

```
function funcWillThrow() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    try {
      throw "Has thrown";
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }, 3000);
}
```

---

Based on your comment below, you may be looking for Promises.  Since the operation is asynchronous and happens outside of the stack which invoked it, in order to catch the error in that stack you'd need to await the operation.  Ideally you'd make use of the `reject` functionality of the `Promise`.  Something like this:

```js
function funcWillThrow() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      reject("Has thrown");
    }, 3000);
  });
}

(async () => {
  try {
    await funcWillThrow();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})();
```

If you specifically need to be able to *throw* from within the `setTimeout` callback, you'd either need to catch there as well:

```js
function funcWillThrow() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      try {
        throw "Has thrown";
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    }, 3000);
  });
}

(async () => {
  try {
    await funcWillThrow();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})();
```

Or customize `setTimeout` itself as a `Promise` and use normal error handling with that:

```js
function myTimeout(ms) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

(async () => {
  try {
    await myTimeout(3000).then(() => {
      throw "Has thrown";
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: The problem with that solution is that, I want to catch the error anywhere `funcWillThrow` is called, not inside it.

Comment: @Joshua: I've updated the answer with some additional options making use of a `Promise`.  Ultimately what you're talking about is an asynchronous operation.  And in order to catch an error from within an asynchronous operation you need to await that operation.

Comment: it works, but not exactly in the way I was hoping, Thanks